# Fatal error: Call to undefined function description_site()

Tags: php

I'm having the following problem:

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function description_site() in
>   C:\AppServ\www\host\includes\site_header.php on line 11

I go to the line. I do not have experience in modifying wrong?
The error in the following line

```
$template->rep_template('{description}',description_site());
```

Picture of the problem to be clarified more

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Call to undefined function description_site()` is pretty auto-explanatory, isn't?

Comment: Thank you, The problem has been resolved.